# How to disable smart quotes

Tags: macos, mac, messages, ichat

[OS X 10.9.3 (Mavericks)] I've disabled smart quotes in the keyboard settings, but whenever I type `'` or `"` in Messages (old name: iChat), they get converted to `‘` and `“`. How do I disable this default conversion?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

In addition to System Preferences, this feature can be turned on and off in each app via Edit > Substitutions.  Make sure you check that setting as well.

Comment: `In addition to System Preferences` I have no idea what this controls, TextEdit? :P

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand your question.

Comment: Don't worry, it was rhetoricle. Anyway, you *cannot* disable it on messages using system preferences.

Comment: Right, but you CAN using the Substitutions menu, and it worked for me. Fantastic! It's suboptimal that I will have to toggle that for whenever I am texting my one friend with a dumb phone, but at least I can!

Comment: No idea why the enable this by default... Thanks

Comment: The setting is under `keyboard -> text`

Comment: @Cilan The system setting seems to apply to the Notes app, at least. And on Sonoma 14.1.2, Apple seems to have messed something up. Disabling it doesn't work. Changing the replacements for double and single quotes has effect. For single quotes, it's possible to select the bottom-most option - the actual single quotes. Which in effect disables smart quotes for single quotes. But for some reason, the bottom-most option for the double quotes is the same as the top-most - "smart" double quotes (on my older MBP running Monterey, the bottom-most option are regular double quotes).

Answer (score 21):

In El Capitan (i.e. 10.11.1), I solved it by changing the Smart Quote settings:

1. Open Keyboard in System Preferences
2. Go to Text tab
3. Change values for "for Double Quotes" and "for Single Quotes" from drop-down selection to use the simple quotes "" rather than ““

That's it. No need to disable or do any other workaround.
Hope this helps, as I had this problem with Message app when posting code.

Comment: Thanks, but this question has been long solved (1 year 4 months). However, this seems like a good alt for el capitan users

Answer (score 18):

Unfortunately none of the posted solutions worked for me. I've solved by changing my keyboard layout from:

- `U.S. International - PC`

to:

- `U.S.`

Comment: Solved for me! You saved a lot of nervous cells of mine, thank you :)

Answer (score 13):

This shell script disables smart quotes in all applications that currently have preferences files:

```
for d in $(defaults domains|tr -d ,);do
  osascript -e "app id \"$d\""&>/dev/null||continue
  defaults write $d SmartQuotes -bool false
  # defaults write $d SmartDashes -bool false
  # defaults write $d SmartLinks -bool false
  # defaults write $d SmartCopyPaste -bool false
  # defaults write $d TextReplacement -bool false
  # defaults write $d CheckSpellingWhileTyping -bool false
done
```

Uncomment the commented out lines to also disable other substitutions or spell checking.

Comment: "all applications that currently have preferences files" - meaning only those where one already made substitution changes?

Comment: i'm guessing this is a bash script?  would be helpful if you mention how and where this code should be executed.  it's potentially very useful but less so without context

Comment: Edit a plain text file called "diablesq.sh", and paste the text into it.

Open a terminal window.

Type "sh disablesq.sh"

Answer (score 13):

#### Disable smart quotes:

`defaults write NSGlobalDomain NSAutomaticQuoteSubstitutionEnabled -bool false`

#### Disable smart dashes:

`defaults write NSGlobalDomain NSAutomaticDashSubstitutionEnabled -bool false`

#### Disable smart quotes for TextEdit:

`defaults write com.apple.TextEdit SmartQuotes -bool false`

#### Disable smart dashes for TextEdit:

`defaults write com.apple.TextEdit SmartDashes -bool false`

Answer (score 5):

In macOS Ventura (13.2):

1. Go to **System Settings** (eg: from the Apple menu)
2. Select **Keyboard** in the left navigation
3. Under **Text Input** click **Edit...**
4. Near the bottom, turn off **Use smart quotes and dashes**

Answer (score 4):

You will find this option in the Keyboard Preferences pane:

- Open System Preferences.
- Click on the Keyboard icon.
- Select the `Text` tab.
- Uncheck the `Use smart quotes and dashes` checkbox.

Note that this is almost a homework question. This is a keyboard/text related setting so it's fairly logical to find it under the Keyboard Preferences.

Comment: In my question I noted that I've tried this and it didn't work. What I had to do was go under Edit -> Substitutions and disable it there through the app itself.